# How can massiv of strings can be converted into Set collection while delegating from Thymleaf in controller in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I write springboot+thymleaf app and i stuck with problems by converting string into Set collection. I had the same application with jsp instead of thymeleaf and had no problems with it. Roles:
             here i have Set of roles(Admin, User) while delegating the values in controller for updating post methos requires them to be converted in string.

```
     @Controller
     @RequestMapping("/admin")
     public class AdminController {
     @Autowired
     UserService userService;

     @Autowired
     private RoleService roleService;

     @Autowired
     BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView showEditProductPage(@PathVariable(name = "id") long id) throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editPage");
    User user = userService.getUserById(id);
    mav.addObject("userEdit", user);
    return mav;

    }
   @PostMapping( "/update")
   public String updateUser(@ModelAttribute("user")  User user) throws Exception {

    Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles().stream()
            .map(Role::getName)
            .map(roleService::findByName)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    user.setRoles(roles);
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userService.updateUser(user);
    return "redirect:/admin/list";
}


     <form   action="#" th:action="@{/admin/update}" th:object="${userEdit}";
      method="post" >

    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">

        <tr>
            <td>UserID</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" />
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{password}" /></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>Roles:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{roles}" /></td>


            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button> </td>
        </tr>
        <a href="/admin/list">List All Users</a>
       </table>
      </form>



      org.springframework.validation.BindException: 
      org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
      Field error in object 'user' on field 'roles': rejected value [USER]; codes 
      [typeMismatch.user.roles,typeMismatch.roles,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments 
      [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.roles,roles]; 
      arguments []; default message [roles]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of 
      type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'roles'; nested exception 
      is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type 
     [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'USER'; nested exception is 
     java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "USER"]



     @Repository
     public class UserHibernateDAO implements UserDAO {

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager entityManager;

     @Override
     public List<User> listAllUsers() {
     return entityManager.
            createQuery("SELECT distinct u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles").getResultList();

    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) throws SQLException {
    entityManager.merge(user);
   }

   @Override
   public void updateUser(User user) throws SQLException {
    Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    currentSession.update(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(Long id) {
    User editUser = (User) entityManager
            .createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.id=:id", User.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
    User userEditById = new User(editUser.getId(), editUser.getUsername(), 
    editUser.getEmail(),editUser.getRoles());
    return userEditById;
    }


    @Service
    public class UserServiceImp implements UserDetailsService, UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> listAllUsers() throws SQLException {
    return userDAO.listAllUsers();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) throws SQLException {
    userDAO.updateUser(user);
   }
```